# How to create a stacked time-series bar chart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working around graphs and am looking for a way to create a graph with its x-axis as percentage (0-100%) and y-axis as DateTime.

I’m able to draw time series bar chart like this, but its not stacked.
[image: time series bar chart]

Or I can draw a simple stacked bar chart, but its x-axis is string and not DateTime.

Is there a way I can customise a chart like this to fit in my scenario.

To get a rough idea, please check out this note.
[image: rough idea]

Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a BarGroupingType widget to the groupingType argument of the BarRendererConfig. Not well documented, but you can find it if you dig into the source code of the BarRendererConfig.

The below code snippet is adapted from:
https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/with_bar_renderer

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
  data,
  animate: true,
  defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig<DateTime>(
    groupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked, \\ add this
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody gets stuck here in future, I was able to do what I wanted to, using the following library. Its presents data beautifully and brilliantly. Also, it provides a good variety of graphs.

SyncFusion Flutter Charts - https://www.syncfusion.com/flutter-widgets/flutter-charts/chart-types